# Failed remote connection to University windows client

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote, remote-access, remote-login

In my university we use Matlab, and to use it at home (to write the lab reports) we need to remote access the client with an RDP file. So, after searching for options I tried using Remmina to access the client. The client's server name appears as a domain link, so I found its IP and entered it in the respective field.

In windows, after opening the file I am supposed to enter "tau\*username*" under the username field for it to select the correct domain, so I figured in Remmina I should just type the domain under the respective field, and so I entered it as "tau". In the "Advanced" tab I chose the "RDP" security option, and in the Startup Program field I left it as it was when I imported the RDP file:

```
||matlab (2)
```

In windows, after entering the password it connects and opens the program, so I entered my password on remmina and clicked "connect". Still, after waiting long enough, I got the message stating:

> Unable to connect to RDP server 1xx.xx.xx.x5

I tried looking for solutions, in vain. Both xrdp and rdesktop have not worked for me, as I didn't understand how to use them. Also, needless to say, I tried leaving the options of the imported  file as they were, but it didn't work either. 
If anyone has any lead as to why this is happening, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have to use a VPN or similar to access your university resources? What output does `nc ip 3389` produce?

Comment: It doesn't produce any output, even after trying it twice

Comment: Without more knowledge about the network set-up in question I recommend that you ask for support from the school’s IT support.

Comment: I don't know what we can do to help you unless you can [edit] your post to include the port your target RDP server is communicating on. VTC as unclear.

Comment: I have no idea how to tell which port it uses... Is it in the RDP file text? Or should I simply include the actual RDP file? When I think about it, it can be found online without special permissions so I won't be violating any privacy or security issues (I found it on my university's website)